# ¿Cómo mostrar diferentes mensajes para cada caso desde una sola consulta de la misma tabla de registros?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo dos consultas, para verificar si el usuario y email están ocupados excepto los mismo datos del usuario.

Mediante estas dos consultas, puedo mostrar mensajes personalizados para cada caso, es decir, para el usuario y para el email.

```
    $stmtA = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username=? AND id_user NOT IN ($id_user) LIMIT 1");
    $stmtA->bind_param("s",$username);
    $stmtA->execute();
    $stmtA->->bind_result($count_user);
    $stmtA->fetch();
    $stmtA->close();

    //Email     
    $stmtB = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email=? AND id_user NOT IN ($id_user) LIMIT 1");
    $stmtB->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmtB->execute();
    $stmtB->->bind_result($count_email);
    $stmtB->fetch();
    $stmtB->close();

//....
} elseif ($count_user===1) {
    echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>El usuario ya esta en uso.</strong>"]);
} elseif ($count_email===1) {
    echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>El correo electrónico ya esta en uso.</strong>"]);
} else {
    //Obtenemos datos una vez los datos sean validados.
    $Uusername = $_POST['username'] ?: '';
    $Uemail = $_POST['email'] ?: '';
    $Upassword = $_POST['password'] ?: '';
}
```

De la misma forma, como lo puedo realizar ese mismo procedimiento en una sola consulta, poder mostrar mensajes personalizados diferentes para ambos casos, o es necesario realizar las dos consultas.

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=? AND id_user NOT IN ($id_user) LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    //$stmt->->bind_result($count_user);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Basta con hacer consultas anidadas mendiante subquery: en la segunda reemplaza IN($iduser) por IN("SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE email=?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrás que cambiar la sql para poder recuperar el usuario y el correo en caso de que devuelva algo:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=? AND id_user NOT IN ($id_user) LIMIT 1");
```

Y enlazas lo que te devuelve con dos variables:

```
$stmt->bind_result($usernameSql, $emailSql);
```

Luego ya simplemente compruebas si la consulta te devuelve registros y cuál de los valores coincide con los que se quiere comprobar:

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($usernameSql == $username) {
         // El usuario es el mismo
    } else if ($emailSql == $email) {
         // El correo es el mismo
    } else {
         // No hay coincidencias (no debería llegar aquí si devuelve datos...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Me gusta la solución, aunque pienso que con el `bind_param()` te has confundido, y te refieras a un `bind_result()`, algo así `$stmt->bind_result($usernameSql, $emailSql);`

Comment: Es verdad, jeje. Perdón. Lo corrijo

Comment: +1 amig@, era solo un pequeño despiste. Saludos

Comment: recordarte que el hecho de informar al usuario que lo que falla es uno u otro campo, da suficiente información para que tu site sea inseguro. Como recomendación, no des esa información.